# Reusing old passwords

Tags: password, security

pam_cracklib module is capable of consulting a user's password "history" and not allowing them to reuse old passwords. 
What security risk is in reusing old passwords?
If this work is useful, how many of password should be kept as history?

Answer (score 1):

It is to prevent user from iterating over two or three passwords every time the mandatory password change happens. This is a risk because this favorite user's password may be already known to the evil guy.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of password changes is to help keep "the evil guy" guessing. This is especially useful if the system has unknowingly already been compromised as it will prevent that invader from being able to easily regain access.

How many passwords to keep in history would really depend on how often you demand a change in password. I have experienced enterprise systems that stored 3 and 5 passwords in history. I don't personally feel this is enough.

I recall Windows 2000 used to store 24 passwords. I remember this as I was working in the university IT department and we discovered a user that would exhaust his password reset history so that he could keep his preferred password.

Here is the recommended policy we settled on back then, which seemed to remedy the problem:

- Enforce password history 5 passwords remembered
- Maximum password age 90 days
- Minimum password age 1 days
- Minimum password length 7 characters
- Password must meet complexity requirements

Hope that helps!